# Retrieve tweets language or filter by language with TwitterStream

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I would like to retrieve or filter by language using `TwitterStream` class. I want to get only tweets of one language or otherwise retrieve everything and then identify each tweet language.

I have build this code but `getIsoLanguageCode()` returns `null` always (see version [3.0.4 JavaDocs](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.4-SNAPSHOT/twitter4j/Status.html)). I think they have problems with this method.

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = TwitterPrintRandomStream.createTwitterConnection();
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        String tw =  status.getText() + " " + status.getIsoLanguageCode();
        System.out.println(tw);
    }
    ...
}
```

I also tried the method `Status.getUser().getLang()` but it returns the user's language not the tweet. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can rely on `iso_language_code` - I couldn't find reference to it in the REST or streaming APIs.

Tweets do have a `lang` attribute which indicates the language that the Tweet was written in. This was [recently added to the API](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/introducing-new-metadata-for-tweets) and, unfortunately, Twitter4J does not yet provide you with access to it.

There is a [task to add it](http://jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-764) in version 3.0.4 but the work does not to appear to have started yet. Unfortunately you'll need to wait until they add it or perhaps you could give them a hand and submit a pull-request.

Comment: Yes I saw it in 3.0.4 and is not working yet, thank you for responding

Answer (score 1):

`status.getPlace().getCountryCode()` should do the trick to get ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 country code

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I'd to get the tweet language not the country

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstooded, I think that language must be attached to tweet to retrieve that. Have you tried to change search operator to `lang:en keyword` or `lang:es` for Spanish, `lang:de` for German and so on?

Comment: Yes and it worked but this is only for the Twitter.Search method, I'd like to retrieve a stream of data, and I think the way is TwitterStream class where I didn't find how to add any operator of language :(

Answer (score 1):

First, Try to get `status.getLang()` and put em into String then compare it with `status.getText()` if match you can get the tweets that only contain language in `status.getLang()`

You can try this following code

```
String filterTweet=null
String language= status.getLang()
String filterLang="(language code)"
If (filterLang.Matches(language)){
filterTweet=status.getText()}
```

Cya